# Converting DMS coordinates to decimal in R

Tags: r

I have a vector of DMS coordinates similar in format to the following:

```
coords <- c("43°46′50″N 79°24′53″W", "43°46′06″N 79°24′46″W")
```

and I would like to convert them into two numeric decimal vectors for latitude and longitude to eventually mark them in `leaflet`.

```
coords_lat <- c(43.780556, 43.768333)
coords_lon <- c(-79.414722, -79.412778)
```

My question is: Is there a function available out there in `R` that does this conversion automatically, or would I need to rely on regex and some outside tool to convert them myself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's the `char2dms` function in the `sp` package that will convert this format, and you'll have to give it the right separator characters. Your example has some interesting separators that I don't have on my keyboard:

```
> coords
[1] "43°46′50″N 79°24′53″W" "43°46′06″N 79°24′46″W"
```

You could cut and paste the separators, or extract the separators from the string, eg:

```
> chd = substr(coords, 3, 3)[1]
> chm = substr(coords, 6, 6)[1]
> chs = substr(coords, 9, 9)[1]
```

Then convert to "DMS" objects:

```
> cd = char2dms(coords,chd=chd,chm=chm,chs=chs)
[1] 43d46'50"W 43d46'6"W
```

Once you've got those, you can convert to numeric with:

```
> as.numeric(cd)
[1] -43.78056 -43.76833
```

To get the lat and the long you'll probably have to split your strings and then use `char2dms`, unless there's something else in the `sp` package....

Note that you can only run `char2dms` on a vector of longs or lats - if you mix them up it fails, interpreting them as whatever the first one is, it seems:

This is a longitude, West:

```
> char2dms(c("23d12'8\"W"))
[1] 23d12'8"W
```

Run it with a vector with a latitude and then a longitude:

```
> char2dms(c("23d12'8\"N","23d12'8\"W"))
[1] 23d12'8"N 23d12'8"S
```

returns two latitude.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if I'm doing something the wrong way but when I used `char2dms` I found the numeric converted value is not correct. Instead I prefer to use the `measurements::convert` function.

This is an example of my results:

```
my_coordinate_1 <- "-99d 36' 15.7\""
my_coordinate_2 <- "-99 36 15.7"
as.numeric(sp::char2dms(my_coordinate_1)) # -98.4 -- WRONG!
measurements:conv_unit(my_coordinate_2, from = "deg_min_sec", to = "dec_deg") # -99.6043611111111 -- RIGHT VALUE!
```

**Update**

Checking on other posts, my problem with the function `sp::char2dms` is related to the missing easting in the coordinates. The function works properly when using

```
my_coordinate <- "99d 36' 15.7\" W" # --99.60436 -- NOW OK!
```

Answer (score 1):

The package [`measurements`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/measurements/measurements.pdf) also provides conversion between decimal degrees and DMS.

Comment: It is always best to include an example rather than a link-only answer.

Comment: Welcome to GIS.se! Please click 'edit' and provide information about the measurements package - links can change or stop working in the future, and best to have some actual descriptions and examples for a good answer here.